# Why isn't the value of class member changing?

Tags: c#

Im fairly new to programming and am making a rpg battle simulator for practice. My problem is that I can't seem to make my attack method work. Heres the classes I have:

```
class Person
{
    protected int attack;
    protected int health;

    public Person(int _attack, int _health)
    {
        attack = _attack;
        health = _health;
    }

    public int GetAttack()
    {
        return attack;
    }

    public int GetHealth()
    {
        return health;
    }

    public int Attack(int _health)
    {
        _health -= attack;
        return _health;
    }
}
class Hero : Person
{
    public Hero(int _attack, int _health)
        :base (_attack , _health)
    {

    }
}
class Enemy : Person
{
    public Enemy(int _attack, int _health)
        :base (_attack , _health)
    {

    }
}
```

and heres the main:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Hero Joe = new Hero(4, 10);
        Enemy Tim = new Enemy(5, 20);

        Joe.Attack(Tim.GetHealth());
        Console.WriteLine(Tim.GetHealth());
        Console.WriteLine(Tim.GetAttack());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

My guess is that the attack method is doing the math, but is never changing the health that is passed into it. Or maybe it has something to do with the fact that their protected. Another thought of mine is that it doesn't need to return anything. 
How would I go about making my attack method work? I just want it to take in somethings health value, subtract the attacking things attack value, and save the calculated value as the health? Thank you for reading this !

Comment: "doing the math, but is never changing the health that is passed into it" is correct.

Comment: @maccettura I use it in the 3rd line of main, making Joe attack Tim.

Comment: @Yummy275 slipped right passed me, sorry.  Im writing you an answer now.

Comment: It should be fairly obvious that there is no code that changes the value of `_attack`.

Comment: As an aside, if you're going to continue programming in c#, you should definitely use idiomatic c# as suggested by the answer of @maccettura (i. e. using properties rather than get/set methods).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass around an `int`, you are making copies of the number, not passing references to the same number in memory.

When you pass around an instance of a class, you *are* passing around references to the same object in memory.

Therefore, I suggest changing your design to something like this:

```
public void Attack(Person target)
{
    target.health -= this.attack;
}

...

Joe.Attack(Jim);
```

Comment: And it reads nicely, as in it's [self documenting code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code).

Comment: That is some clean looking code ! Thank you! I have never encountered the "this" keyword before, so I'll look into that !

Comment: @Yummy275 `this` is entirely redundant here, and is merely added for aesthetic reasons.  It would behave identically if you just removed it.

Answer (score 3):

You got a couple things you can improve here.  First thing is naming conventions, I recommend reading the [design guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions).

First, If you change your Attack and Health to properties instead of protected fields, you expose getter and setter methods for it.  Obviously you only want to set form the controller so make the `set` a `private set`:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Attack { get; private set; }
    public int Health { get; private set; }

    public Person(int attack, int health)
    {
        Attack = attack;
        Health = health;
    }

    // Rest of code
}
```

When  you do it like this you eliminate the need for your individual `GetAttack()` and `GetHealth()` methods.

Next, the names of your parameter in `Attack()` is misleading.  I assume you want the parameter to be "attack" and not "health" right?  Since our setter is private this method allows us to only access health modifications *inside* the class. Since we already changed `Health` to be a property, we don't need to return it anymore so this method can now be `void`:

```
//Our property is named Attack so this has to be AttackAction or something different
public void AttackAction(int attack)
{
    Health -= attack;
}
```

And if we put it all together:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Attack { get; private set; }
    public int Health { get; private set; }

    public Person(int attack, int health)
    {
        Attack = attack;
        Health = health;
    }

    public void AttackAction(int attack)
    {
        Health -= attack;
    }
}

public class Hero : Person
{
    public Hero(int attack, int health)
        :base (attack , health)
    {

    }
}

public class Enemy : Person
{
    public Enemy(int attack, int health)
        :base (attack , health)
    {

    }
}
```

I made a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ltWOND) that shows this new code in action.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `Attack()` but are never saving the value returned by that method. You need to add a Setter for the `health` field, then set that value to the method's returned value. Something like

**Health Property**

```
public int Health
{
    get { return health; }
    set { health = value; }
}
```

**Setting the Value**

```
Tim.Health = Joe.Attack(Tim.Health);
```

Comment: Based on the names of these properties, I don't know why someone would have to expose this code (Repetitively).  The method itself should be the source for who and what happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the design pattern the same (you don't, see Blorgbeard's answer) you could add a `SetHealth()` method to Person and do something like this:

```
Tim.SetHealth(Joe.Attack(Tim.GetHealth());
```

This gets Tim's health total, passes that to Joe's attack method, which returns a value (what Tim's new health total should be) and then Tim's health is set to this value.